# How to find the file from its content by HTML code

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have more than 100 files in my local drive D:/DOC/
I used HTML code to list the file on webpage.
But i cant able to find the file with inside contend.

EG:- file55,file22 and file81 have the particular word like "Linux"

can you help to create HTML code to search the files which are have particular word like "Linux"

I make simple format to list the files in D:\DOC\ location.

idex.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Document Frames</title>
    </head>


<frameset cols ="30%,*%">


    <frame src="test1.html" name="menu_SC_page" />


    <frame src="test2.html" name="main1page" />


</frameset>


</html>
```

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#999898">

<a href="D:\Doc\"  target="main1page"   >Document</a><br /><br />

</body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
empty file only
```

Comment: So you want to search ALL 100 files and find any cases with "Linux" in them? Also, what do you want to do once you find these cases? Do you want to replace them with something else?

Comment: Yes i need to find the file which contain word the "linux" in that 100 files
and list those particular files 
like :- word present in 
file55,
file22 and 
file81

but i no need to replace the word.

i like get like search engine

Comment: It is not possible to `create HTML code to search the files`, as HTML code is language meant to only present some things in the web browser. HTML cannot open files, search through files, edit files.

Comment: Is there any other way to find from the web browser

Comment: If you want to search all 100 files. You don't need code to do it. You can simply use a text editor to do it. I use Sublime. You can search the entire directory for a word like "Linux" and it'll open all files that have that word in it.

Comment: is that possible to create like search engine.
I can use the same way in my office to, there i cant use other tool.
cant use portable too.